# How to add ckeditor for multiple textarea with same name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, ckeditor

```
<div>
<textarea class="input-area additional" name="research_projects[]" placeholder="Project Details" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<textarea class="input-area additional" name="research_projects[]" placeholder="Project Details" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</div>
```

These are 2 textareas with identical name **research_projects[ ]**. And it is dynamic also, multiple of those textareas can be added. So how can I add ckeditor to all those textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Give them different IDs and do

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name^=research_projects]")
  .forEach(elem => CKEDITOR.replace(elem.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue for submitting the form with add more button and the dynamic jquery content.
CKEditor maybe not work with class and ids,
What I do.

> Give the different name to all textarea the CKEditor will work when
> the user submits the form than before submitting form change the name
> values

**like**

```
$("#submitButton).click(function(){
$(".input-area additional").each(function(){
$(this).attr("name","research_projects[]");

})
$("#form").submit();
})
```

I hope this idea will work for you.
Thanks